# Non used assumption in calculations of stationary process

Tags: time-series, stationarity

Let $W_t$ be a complex-valued stochastic process such that
$$W_t = \sum_{l=-L}^L
C_le^{
2iπf_lt}$$
where $C_l$
is a complex-valued rv such that
$\Bbb E{(C_l)} = 0, \Bbb E(C_l^2)
< ∞, |l| ≤ L < ∞$
Also assume $f_l$
is a fixed real-valued constant with $f_{−l} = −f_l$
. Show that if $C_l$ are uncorrelated then $W_t$
is a stationary process.

By linearity, we have that $\Bbb E(W_t)=0$ $\forall t$.

Then, $Var(W_t)=\sum_{i=-L}^L\sum_{j=-L}^L e^{2iπf_it}e^{-2iπf_jt}Cov(C_i,C_j)=\sum_{i=-L}^L
Var(C_l)<\infty$

Finally, let $h$ be a lag, $$Cov(W_{t+h},W_{s+h})=\sum_{i=-L}^L\sum_{j=-L}^L e^{2iπf_i(t+h)}e^{-2iπf_j(s+h)}Cov(C_i,C_j)$$
$$=\sum_{i=-L}^L\sum_{j=-L}^L e^{2iπf_it}e^{-2iπf_js}Cov(C_i,C_j)=Cov(W_{t},W_{s})$$

So $W_t$ is stationary but I don't see where we should have used that $f_{−l} = −f_l$.

Did I got it wrong somewhere ?

Comment: The statement of this question is strange insofar as "$l$" appears to refer to three different things: (1) the index of "a fixed real-valued constant," (2) a quantified parameter "$|l|\lt L,$" and (3) the bound index of a summation.  It would help to resolve those inconsistencies.  I would guess you mean only that *for all $l$ with $L\le l\le L,$ $f_l=-f_l.$*

Comment: @whuber to me it is meant that $f_1=-f_{-1}$ for example, a fact that I never use in my solution